# Accelerating Expansion

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion

If observed galaxies at twice the distance move away at twice the speed, but are also twice as far away temporally, wouldnt that indicate the expansion was faster at earlier times? This seems counter to accelerated expansion. Please clarify.

Comment: As it stands, it's unclear what you're asking. Also, it seems like you're quoting Hubble's law, which, on its own, doesn't determine whether expansion is accelerating or decelerating.

Comment: The heart of my question boils down to this. Does the observable universe appear denser at further distances, due to the observed light coming from the more distant past?

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at the situation carefully.

All galaxies could be traced back to a single point. We can say that all galaxies were at the same place at the same time at the time of the big bang. (Some galaxies could have been formed later but just stick with me)

The galaxies that are further away are moving faster like you said.

Now can we assume that the galaxy that is further away was moving faster, to begin with, and the ones that behind were slower anyway and that is why they are so far behind? Maybe.

A simple test would be to measure the speed of the galaxy today. Measure the speed of the same galaxy a few days from now. Is it accelerated or slowed down or is the unchanged? What we found out that the speed is accelerated and it's just not with one galaxy, it's the same case with all of them.

I just tried to simplify this to explain. It is much more complex than this but I hope you get the idea.

**EDIT**:

We observe that the light coming from distant galaxies are shifted towards red. The reasoning is that space is expanded and therefore the light wave is "expanded" and therefore the light appears to be red. We are soon launching a new satellite that would detect infrared light which would be coming from galaxies that are further away than the ones that we have observed so far. The light waves coming from those galaxies are expanded much more. This is one problem that we found a solution for. Another problem is that we can only see the brightest stars. The further away they are, the harder it is to observe them. We need better technologies and theories because we can't rely on light or gravity at the moment to measure the density and therefore we can't really say if the outer space is dense or not. There are theories surrounding it but more research and development is needed to test those theories.

Comment: I get that the experiment to measure the speed of things expanding is carried out and recorded over time to determine that the expansion is accelerating, i guess my question is, what effect does looking back through spacetime have on the measurements? There has to be some kind of distortion associated with those long distance measurements, as far as i can figure. Does the universe appear less dense locally than at long distances?

Comment: Let me update my answer to address this.